# Multiple bean validators per input field

Tags: validation, jsf-2

Is it possible to have multiple validators for this input field?

I.e. SearchAuditLogBackingBean.validate1(), SearchAuditLogBackingBean.validate2().

```
<p:inputTextarea id="searchCriteria"
  validator="#{searchAuditLogBackingBean.validateSearchCriteria}">
</p:inputTextarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<f:validator>` to register multiple validators. They will be invoked in the order they are been declared. You should only put the validate methods in a fullworthy `@FacesValidator` class instead of in a backing bean.

```
<p:inputTextarea id="searchCriteria">
    <f:validator validatorId="searchCriteriaValidator" />
    <f:validator validatorId="someOtherValidator" />
</p:inputTextarea>
```

with

```
@FacesValidator("searchCriteriaValidator")
public class SearchCriteriaValidator implements Validator {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
@FacesValidator("someOtherValidator")
public class SomeOtherValidator implements Validator {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi BalusC I knew this option but i also saw from your other posts that such validator doesn't go well with EJB DI. i.e. Injecting into the validator class an EJB resource.

Comment: Change `@FacesValidator` by `@ManagedBean` and use `binding="#{searchCriteriaValidator}"` instead of `validatorId`.